# Android: how to send ImageView to ScrollView with a button

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, imageview, scrollview

I want to send a imageview from bx.xml  to a layout in another.xml(activity_main) with a button content  in the.xml  (activity_main).
this is bx.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher30005"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"

        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher22" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/bSetWall"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="400dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Imposta come sfondo"

        />
</LinearLayout>
```

in another. xml i have the resource of button and also the layout where it needs to go the imageview and is this:button and also the layout where it needs to go the imageview and is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="702dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bopentx"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="tattoo" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bopensax"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="sand" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bopenwx"
         android:layout_width="100dp"
         android:layout_height="100dp"
         android:layout_gravity="left"
         android:text="wet" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bopennx"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="naked" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Bopenlx"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="loincloth" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Bopenbx"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="brazilian" />

     </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/Scroll1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Linear1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="702dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

 //the image needs to go here when i click the button


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and in the menu class i have used this :

```
public class menu extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     Button button1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bopennx);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            switch (v.getId()){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bx, null);  

                LinearLayout imageScrollLayout = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.Linear1);
                ImageView  newImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                newImageView.setImageResource(R.id.imageView1);
                imageScrollLayout.addView(newImageView);
                break

}
        }});
        }
```

the problem in logcat is:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.culiperfettihd.menu$1.onClick(menu.java:67)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17267)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set the image resource to an `ImageView` it needs to be a `drawable`. If you want the newly created `ImageView` to have the same image as the first then change

```
newImageView.setImageResource(R.id.imageView1);
```

to

```
newImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher22);
```

You can't actually place it in the `layout` at runtime. You can add it as you are trying to do but you need to use a valid `resource id` and not another `view`

Comment: now does not give me any problems, but I do not send the image in the layout

Comment: Since you aren't actually creating a new `ImageView` why not just put it in the xml before you compile and set `android:visibility="gone` then set it to `VISIBLE` when you click the `Button`?

Comment: You haven't given your `LinearLayout` an `id` so `imageScrollLayout` is `null` when you try to assign it here `LinearLayout imageScrollLayout = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.Linear1);`

Comment: I gave the id in the. xml: <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/Scroll1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:id="@+id/Linear1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="702dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
 
 //the image needs to go here when i click the button
          
            
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

Comment: You are `inflating` the original xml which doesn't have those `Views`. You need to `inflate` whatever that xml file is

Comment: i  changed with: View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null); but nothing

Comment: i have inflating now the .xml where it needs to go to the image and before that where he was the image

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just having a little trouble understanding what you have/want. Why don't you set up a second `Activity` that opens when you click the `Button` with the new `layout` instead of inflating it?

Comment: well I know open an activity that displays the image I want, but I want to send a picture that is in the bx.xml to make it display nell'activitymain. xml through the use of a button. for example the new gallery android that when clicking a folder opens the ScrollView of all the images that are contained

Comment: Not exactly. But if I could understand the error you have we could figure it out

Comment: well i have a activity_main.xml and inside there are two layouts and a scrollview each, in a layout there are some bottons, and another layout i want send the image with the click of one of the buttons

Comment: for example in the gallery android there are folders on the left and on the right the images are displayed based on the folder that is clicked

Comment: Ok, you need to look into using [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)

Comment: sorry but I've never used fragment

Comment: thanks a lot friend I solved in another way, but thank you so much for your time

Comment: You're welcome. I was trying to figure out what exactly you had. Glad you got it figured out